# How do i can get document.body styles in jest or how i can test this code inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, ts-jest

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvYA9.png)

useEffect(() => {
let top = 10;

```
if (window.innerWidth > frame.current.clientHeight) {
  top = Math.max(top, (window.innerHeight - frame.current.clientHeight) / 2 - top);
}
frame.current.style.marginTop = `${top}px`;
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
return () => {
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
}
```